# Как правильно: "абстрактный художник" или "художник-абстракционист"?

Tags: словообразование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, допустимо ли использовать выражение "абстрактный художник" (встретила такое использование на одном из интернет-ресурсов - режет слух, будто "условный художник"), или всё же корректней "художник-абстракционист"?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: абстрактный художник = художник, рассматриваемый в качестве абстракции. Правильный ответ: художник-абстракционист.

Answer (score 2):

Разумеется не графический художник, а художник-график, не монументальный, а монументалист, не карикатурный, а карикатурист... Специализация, никак не ограничивающая сферу его деятельности, идёт вторым номером составного слова.

> Топ-5 известных художников-маринистов: Айвазовский, Афремов, Чебоха,
> Форман, Бонд.

Перед определяемым словом принято отмечать (наряду с эпитетами) место приложения труда: *театральный*, *музейный*, *придворный*.

> Украинский оперный художник-сценограф Е. Лысык.